# PHP - Insert date into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, insert, format

I am trying to insert date into mysql but everytime it fails and comes out as `0000-00-00` in phpmyadmin

My date format is like `2012-08-06` (yyyy-mm-dd) and the date field type in database is `date`.

```
$date = "2012-08-06";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO data_table (title, date_of_event) 
             VALUES('". $_POST['post_title'] ."',
                    '". $date ."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

tried changing `-` to `/` or removing them, it doesn't work.

Comment: I suggest using timestamps (`time()`) instead of date. and use the `date()` function to convert it to any format when displaying.

Comment: you have two problems (sql injection vulnerability and usage of an old, soon to be deprecated extension) that can be both solved if you switch to PDO (or mysqli)

Comment: @MakuraYami Why is that ? can you explain a little ?

Comment: @mishu yes I am aware of both problems :) it's just I found about PDO and mysqli yesterday and I want to finish up the coding then convert the extension and fix security problems.

Comment: @xperator, When you use timestamp it saves your time as a int. which will never give problems as you are having now. and it has the advantage of being able to be written out in ANY date format without any risky string-to-date functions.

Comment: This problem cannot be reproduced with the current [mcve] and therefore should be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try `CAST` function in MySQL:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO data_table (title, date_of_event)
VALUES('". $_POST['post_title'] ."',
CAST('". $date ."' AS DATE))") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: try again there was one extra comma

Comment: whats is the exact data type of your field `date_of_event`?

Comment: oops I had a tiny problem with that comma. fixed and works now :)

Comment: A prepared statement should be used for security/stability.  This snippet should not be used in any professional code.

Answer (score 16):

try

```
$date = "2012-08-06";
$date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date));
```

Comment: I agree with @Mike here, what's the difference between the two? http://codepad.org/KFF4pi5u (except for making the script a bit more complicated)

Comment: Well in past I encountered with same problem, and the way i did work.

Again, I just tried to insert date as xperator did, the date was inserted. @xperator, will you mind printing the sql statement?

Comment: This answer is nonsense -- it makes no change to the string.  No one should be implementing this non-solution. Code-only answers are low value on Stack Overflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to insert different dates than "today", you can use CURDATE():

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO data_tables (title, date_of_event) VALUES ("%s", CURDATE())';
$sql = sprintf ($sql, $_POST['post_title']);
```

PS! Please do not forget to sanitize your MySQL input, especially via mysql_real_escape_string ()

Comment: No it's not the current date, today date was just an example :)

Comment: A prepared statement should be used for security/stability.  This snippet should not be used in any professional code.

Answer (score 0):

try converting the date first.

```
$date = "2012-08-06";

mysql_query("INSERT INTO data_table (title, date_of_event)
               VALUES('" . $_POST['post_title'] . "',
                      '" . $date . "')") 
           or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: A prepared statement should be used for security/stability.  This snippet should not be used in any professional code.

Answer (score 0):

**How to debug SQL queries when you stuck**

Print you query and run it directly in mysql or phpMyAdmin

```
$date = "2012-08-06";
$query= "INSERT INTO data_table (title, date_of_event) 
             VALUES('". $_POST['post_title'] ."',
                    '". $date ."')";
echo $query;
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

that way you can make sure that the problem is not in your PHP-script, but in your SQL-query

**How to submit questions on SQ-queries**

Make sure that you provided enough closure

- Table schema
- Query
- Error message is any

Comment: A prepared statement should be used for security/stability.  This snippet should not be used in any professional code.

Answer (score -1):

```
$date=$year."-".$month."-".$day; 
$new_date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dob)); 
$status=0;  
$insert_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");  
$latest_insert_id=0; 

$insertSql="insert into participationDetail (formId,name,city,emailId,dob,mobile,status,social_media1,social_media2,visa_status,tnc_status,data,gender,insertDate)values('".$formid."','".$name."','".$city."','".$email."','".$new_date."','".$mobile."','".$status."','".$link1."','".$link2."','".$visa_check."','".$tnc_check."','".json_encode($detail_arr,JSON_HEX_APOS)."','".$gender."','".$insert_date."')";
```

Comment: A prepared statement should be used for security/stability.  This snippet should not be used in any professional code.  Furthermore, code-only answers are low value on Stack Overflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.