# PHP date() format when i insert into datetime in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

What is the correct format to pass to the date() function in PHP if I want to insert the result into a MySQL datetime type column?

I've been trying date("Y-M-D G:i:s") but that just inserts "0000-00-00 00:00:00" everytime.

Comment: date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $date ) );

Comment: RTM's http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php --- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Insert date into mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827175/php-insert-date-into-mysql)

Comment: MySQL only support Y-M-D

Answer (score 3):

You have two options on formatting a datetime ready for mysql:

```
$date = '04 nov 2016 15:59:25';

$one  = new DateTime( $date );
echo $one->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );

$two  = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $date ) );
echo $two;
```

Providing that the format in the end is `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` then you should be good with mysql datetime columns