# How to fix date error 0000-00-00 in phpmyadmin?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have this error. I already manage to insert my data in database. but the problem is my date in 0000-00-00. What is the error? I tried to change the format but also the same. I'll attach my code.

### error

[image]

### php code.

```
<?php

        include ('connect.php');

        $book = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'check',FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);

   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
$c_id = 4;
$date_today = $_POST['frmDateReg'];
$service_date = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'pickup_date',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$masa = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'pagi',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$datetoday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date_today));

$sql2 = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO booking(bookDate,serviceDate,bookTime,cust_fk) VALUES ($datetoday,$service_date,$masa,$c_id)" );
```

?>

### html code

```
<input type="date" class="textbox" id="pick_date" name="pickup_date" /></p>
 <input type="text" name="frmDateReg"  id="frmDate" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?>" readonly="">

  <script type="text/javascript">

    let dateInput = document.getElementById('pick_date');
    const cur_date = new Date();
    cur_date.setDate(cur_date.getDate() + 3);
     var dateStr = cur_date.toISOString().split("T")[0];;
     dateInput.setAttribute('min', dateStr);

     </script>
```

Comment: What datatype are the `bookDate` and `serviceDate` columns in MySQL?

Comment: both column i put DATE value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Insert date into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827175/php-insert-date-into-mysql)

Comment: i triede nothing works

Comment: The date that is being inserted from PHP is `date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date_today)` but MySQL expects the format to be `yyyy-mm-dd` casted to a date using MySQL's `CAST` method; let me know if that helps.

Comment: $sql2 = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO booking(bookDate,serviceDate,bookTime,cust_fk) VALUES (CAST ( '". $datetoday. "' AS DATE ,CAST ('". $service_date ."' AS DATE),$masa,$c_id)");
is it like this? or my code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i already found my answer for my problem.

```
$sql2 = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO booking(bookDate,serviceDate,bookTime,cust_fk) VALUES ( '$date','$service_date',$masa,$c_id)" );
```

the error is in this line. i forget to put  ' ' on the $date and $service_date. lol

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save NULL if the variable is not required or empty, you can try below codes.

```
$service_date = $service_date? date_format($service_date,"Y-m-d H:i:s") : NULL ;

$sql2 = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO booking(bookDate,serviceDate,bookTime,cust_fk) VALUES ( '$date', $service_date,$masa,$c_id)" );
```